# ActionItem appears on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have 3 fragments: `A, B, C` and `ActionItem` called `Filters`. These `Filters` should be visible only when Fragment `A` is visible respectively.

So I hide `Filters` when `B` or `C` is substituted over `A` and restore them back when `A` is replaced back.

That works fine unless I change orientation of screen. `Filters` become visible after it.

**What have I tried:**

in Activity which stands for Fragments navigation override `onConfigurationChanged()` I check the visible `Fragment` and if its `B` or `C` i `hideActionFilters()`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
....//other logic

//check if backStack empty
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        //check top fragment by position and name in backstack
        //LessonsFragment - B; SingleLessonFragment - C
        if (getTopFragment().getClass().getName().equals(LessonsFragment.class.getName()) ||
                getTopFragment().getClass().getName().equals(SingleLessonFragment.class.getName())) {
            hideActionFilterItem();
        }
    }
```

That doesn't work. 
Method `hideActionItem()`:

```
    private void hideActionFilterItem() {
    View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_filters);
    if (menuItemView != null) {
        menuItemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Tried to debug, it runs `hideActionItem()` but `ActionItem` still visible.

Also I have tried to hide in `onPause()`; in `onConfogChanged()` of Fragment `B` and `C`.

Probably someone had such problem. Please help.

*P.S. Please tell me if some more code needed. Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing orientation, the view is completely recreated so you need to handle your situation in onCreate().

The fragment to be displayed is handled automatically by the FragmentManager, but I think you have to "respecify" each time the view is created, that the Filters should be hidden. I suggest you look if Fragment A is visible and if not, call your hideActionItem() method :

```
public void onCreate (){
...
//Get the Fragment A using the fragmentManager
  FragmentA frag = (FragmentA)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(the_tag_you_used_to_add_the_fragment);
  if(frag!=null){
    if(!frag.isVisible())
       hideActionItem();
    }
   else hideActionItem();
}
```